# What is the difference between functional relationship and functioning relationship?

Tags: adjectives, nouns, uncountable-nouns

What is the difference between

- functional relationship
- functioning relationship

Comment: A thing can be functional. A thing can be functioning. A functional thing can be non-functioning. In that case, we might say that it's a non-functioning functional thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/functional) list these three "simple definitions" of ***functional***...

> 1: *designed to have a practical use*
>    2: (medical) *affecting the way a part of your body works*
>    3: *working properly*

...where sense #3 is synonymous with ***functioning***, but as implied by [@Damkerng T.'s comment above](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/86750/what-is-the-difference-between-functional-relationship-and-functioning-relations#comment167724_86750) obviously it's possible something that's *expected* to be of practical use (be functional) might not actually be working properly. So it's possible to have a non-functioning functional relationship.

I would just add that I think M-W's first definition above is slightly more restrictive than it should be. A relationship might simply *arise* (or *be identified*) that was primarily noted for its *functional* effects even if it wasn't actually "designed" (by engineers, God, evolution, etc.). And at any given point in time that relationship might (temporarily) not be performing as ***expected*** (not necessarily as ***designed***).

Going further in that direction, I could also imagine using *functional relationship* to describe a relationship that was *based on functionality*. For example, relationships with others in the workplace might arose solely because of the functions you and they perform at work (and in some cases those relationships might not even *have* any practical use, for either the workers or the employer).

That's to say, ***functional*** can have a range of meanings (broadly, *having to do with functionality*), whereas ***functioning*** only ever means *working [properly]*.

Answer (score 0):

By a quick dictionary search you can find out that the word "functional" is an adjective. In fact, there are many words with -al endings that are adjectives, such as electrical, divisional, internal...
There is not much more to add to that, it's just a typical every-day adjective.

Now, the word "functioning" is an adjective as well. It is actually something that is called present participle adjective. Verbs have the present participle form, and you may remember it from continuous tenses. It is formed by adding the ending -ing to verbs e.g. functioning, working, swimming, praying...
These kinds of adjectives have a special use:

> "Present participles (-ing) are used to describe the people or things that cause the feelings."

Quoted from [here](https://staff.washington.edu/marynell/grammar/partadj.html).

You can find similar explanations on other sites as well, such as [this one](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/support-files/participle_adjectives_long_list.pdf).

So to take some examples, "boring news", "annoying noise", "terrifying movie" would respectively mean news that cause boredom, noise that causes annoyance, movie that causes terror. Consequently, "functioning relationship" would mean a relationship that causes function, which doesn't really make sense to me. So you should always say "functional" relationship, not "functioning".

Comment: I checked it in Macmillan dictionary and it says functioning is a noun.